# How to stop co-routine?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

When two co-routines are running, how do you stop the first co-routine?

```
GLOBALS.stableTime = 5;

IEnumerator StableWaittingTime ()
{
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (1f);
        if (GLOBALS.stableTime == 0) {
                GameManager.instance.LevelFaildMethod ();
        } else {
                GameManager.instance.stableWaittingTime.text = GLOBALS.stableTime.ToString ();
                GLOBALS.stableTime--;
                StartCoroutine ("StableWaittingTime");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@**Imapler** answer is almost all you need. I would just add that `StopCoroutine` method of `MonoBehaviour` is overloaded and has 3 types of parameters, so it is possible to stop many coroutines of same name.
For your need here, just use yield break; like this:

```
void Start () 
{
    StartCoroutine (StableWaittingTime ());
}

IEnumerator StableWaittingTime ()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (1f);
    if (false) 
    {
        // do something
    } 
    else 
    {
        // do something
        StartCoroutine (StableWaittingTime ());
        yield break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There are three ways to stop coroutines.

1. The first is to call `StopAllCoroutines()`, which will obviously stop all running coroutines.
2. The second is to call `StopCoroutine(coroutine)`, where `coroutine` is a variable name given to your `IEnumerator`.
3. And the third is to do a `yield break` from within the coroutine.

Worth noting is that both StopAllCoroutines and StopCoroutine can only stop a coroutine when the coroutine reaches a `yield return *`.

So if you have two coroutines with the same name and you want to stop the one you are executing in you do `yield break`.
Interestingly, if you want to stop every other coroutine besides the one you are executing in, you call `StopCoroutines()` from within that coroutine.

Comment: Thnx Impler , But at a same time both co-routines are running and i want to when second co-routine is start before it first co-routine i want to stop how it can possible you have any idea?

Comment: Its a bit hard to understand you but i think you mean that first you have one coroutine started and when you start your second you want to stop the first, is this correct?

Comment: Yea Absolutely your understanding is correct and because that i want to handle 4-5 co-routines at the same time so can you help me regarding my question ?

Comment: i dont use diffrent co-routines , i use same co-routines for all.

Comment: Then your only choice is to either cancel the one you are in by yield break or cancel all except the one you are in by using StopCoroutine

Comment: Also, you can pass control flag to coroutine (wrapper class with bool member). Raise this flag from main loop and check this flag in coroutine loop and do **yield break** when flag is raised.