# Unity stop and start coroutines

Tags: unity-game-engine, coroutine

How can I have a function which will play a coroutine, but first check if it is already running to stop it if it is?

**EDIT**: Sorry I didnt see that someone had already asked/answered this and it was something I was stuck on for a bit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop co-routine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25204035/how-to-stop-co-routine)

Comment: it's a great tip, Justin, but already features on the site.  indeed it's a shame there are dozens of duplicates (folks should have marked them as "duplicates" along the way)

Comment: Hi @MickyD thanks i didnt realise I couldnt just post code snippits. Will keep the question & answer SO theme for next time- have modified this question for now

Comment: @JustinHirsch no problem Justin. I just snipped out your "question" to read more like a question, feel free to flesh it out :)

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour 
{
  [SerializeField] // Allow the variable to be edited in editor
  private float parameterValue; 
  private IEnumerator coroutine;

  private IEnumerator CoroutineA(float _parameter)
  { // do something, usually for _parameter time }

  private void StartDoSomething () 
  { 
    if (coroutine != null)
      StopCoroutine(coroutine); // no overlaps on timers etc

    coroutine = CoroutineA(parameterValue);
    StartCoroutine(coroutine);
  }
}
```

OR see linked answer:
[How to stop co-routine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25204035/how-to-stop-co-routine?lq=1)